# Mailman - Send out emails at different times depending on the timezone of the user?

Tags: email, mailing-list, timezone, mailman

We need to send out regular emails to people, and we're thinking about using a mailman list. However one requirement is that we want each user to get the email at a different time. We want them to get it at the same time, local time. So if we have 2 users, one in London and the other in Paris, and we want them both to get an email at 9:30am, we could send the email at 9:30am UTC and we want the Londoner and Parisian to get the email at 9:30am local time, (which could be at 9:30am UTC, 10:30am UTC or 11:30am UTC depending on the time of the year). The email body would be the same for all users. Also assume we have a database of all the timezones for each email address on our list.

Is there some way in mailman to do this, or do we have to roll our own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you know that there is no guarantee with e-mail that it arrives at a certain time, that people could access the mail from different locations at varying time zones etc.. However, I understand the requirements (I had a client who was just asking for this, too:)

Default Mailman does not have any such feature built in. Nor are there filter criteria for e.g. selectively dealing with parts of subscribers. I also do not know about any add-ons that could do this.

Of course, you could set up lists for each time zone. But this means quite some administrative overhead, people will get messages with different list-ids, you'd have to think about dealing with different bounce addresses and such.

Since you probably want to do announcements only (versus discussion lists what Mailman is designed for) I recommend you write some simple scripts to send the messages. If you have a list of addresses and time zones this should be no problem. HTH.

Comment: yes that's pretty much the conclusion I've come to.

Answer (score 0):

Is the email content all the same? How do you plan on getting their local time? As far as I know, Mailman doesn't have any facility to capture that information. This sounds like something you will have to write

Comment: yeah the email body is the same. Let's assume I already have a list of email addresses to timezones.